# How can one equip armour pieces in Creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is it possible to put chest plate and other on the character in Creative mode?

He can dress in survival mode, and wants to open a new world in Creative mode. 
In Creative mode, he has the diamond chest plate in the bottom of the screen, he picks it up, and turn on third person view, then the character holds the armour in his hand, and not on his body.

He wants to have the chest plate on the body of his character, is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "dress"? Do you mean armors?

Comment: he wants to use different helmets, chest plates and leggings and such

Comment: I'm 70% confident that you can still dress a character in armors and such.  The only real restriction is that infinite/flat assumes that the world is empty of resources. (Which is only useful for pre-bulding an adventure/puzzle map or having it as a creative canvas.)  As such, you wouldn't be able to "dress" if you can't make the items.  Other then that, if those items where to appear though some other means, you can still wear them as normal.

Comment: Thank you.he tries like he does in survival mode, but in this mode the character just holds the thing he tries to dress with, in his hand. He talks about an update, but there is no update available? He has teh items

Comment: By chance, is the player putting the items on the toolbar on the bottom (which are like your hands) or on his character portrait? (Which is on the top half of the screen when picking items)  I think here is where the confusion lies.  (If anyone wants to do a write-up, make sure to attach a picture as to where access the character window from creative)

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I'm thinking the actual question here is how to equip armour in creative mode.

Comment: Look at this link: https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/how_to_use_armor.php and then scroll to where it says "Put on Armor in Creative Mode". I have a feeling this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've updated the title to reflect the question and retagged as [minecraft-pocket-edition] as the original had [minecraft] and [ios] tags.

Answer (score 0):

As the new update of 0.14.2, you can now put items onto your inventory to keep them. You can also add them to your armor slots now too. All you need to do is go in the armor slot and pick the armor you want to put on and your done.

Answer (score -2):

As of 0.11, the answer is yes, but it's a little complicated.
There are two ways to do it.

#### Way 1

this first one requires a paid app called Plug PE, costing $3 (Canada here). If you download it, simply open the app, wait for it to load, then open PE. (Both apps should be already running in the background) Then use the game settings to change your gamemode to survival. open chat and type `.g <Item name, no spaces>`, equip it, and head back into creative.

#### Way 2

You can do it for free by doing this: In your creative flatworld, take out wood and stone, then, spawn ~30 cows if you want leather, or put down 5 blocks of iron for iron gear, of lastly, 5 diamond or gold blocks and 1 iron for diamond or gold. then change your gamemode to survival, punch the wood, mine the stone with a wood pick, make a stone pick or sword, kill the cows if you want leather, or mine the iron for ore gear and then the gold or diamond. then craft your armour and head into creative.

*Done!*